# Share Headless Fragment Between Activities

Tags: android, android-fragments

For some reason my understanding was that a headless Fragment lives for the duration of your application. With this understanding, in my attempt to persist an object between startActivityForResult() I put the object in a Headless Fragment like this

```
    private HeadlessFragment modelFragment;
    modelFragment = (HeadlessFragment)
 getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Constants.HEADLESS_FRAGMENT_TAG);
            if (modelFragment == null){
                modelFragment = new HeadlessFragment();
            }
    modelFragment.setInvoice(invoice);
```

I can confirm that the custom object was set, however when I go to the next activity and try to get the same object by calling findFragmentByTag with same tag the object is null.

Does a Headless Fragment survive between two Activities life cycle? I did set setRetainInstance(true) on that Headless Fragment. I was hoping that I will not have to implement Parceable on my custom object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For some reason my understanding was that a headless Fragment lives for the duration of your application.

No. Fragments are owned by activities and are not application-wide constructs.

> I can confirm that the custom object was set, however when I go to the next activity and try to get the same object by calling findFragmentByTag with same tag the object is null.

There are at least two reasons for this:

First, at least in the code that you are showing, you never add the fragment to the `FragmentManager` via a `FragmentTransaction`. As such, the activity that created the fragment will not be able to find the fragment via `findFragmentByTag()`, because the `FragmentManager` does not know about it.

Second, each activity has its own `FragmentManager`, and fragments from one activity are not accessible in another activity.

> I was hoping that I will not have to implement Parceable on my custom object.

Then don't pass the object. Pass the information (e.g., a key or ID) by which the other activity can retrieve the object (from a singleton POJO cache, by querying the database, etc.).

Or, do not make them separate activities, but have them as separate (regular) fragments in one activity.

Or, implement `Serializable`, though `Parcelable` executes more quickly.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I will bite the bullet and implement parcelable.